# Split cols, bind dfs and keep most repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a `df` looking like this:

```
> df

Names   Symbol  GeneID  Description    Paths                Colors
IL-1    CP1     3553    Receptor       Path1|Path2|Path5    Green|Blue|Pink
IL-6    CFT5    3569    Receptor       Path3|Path1|Path2    Red|Green|Blue
TNF     DFR4    7124    Receptor       Path4|Path3|Path1    Yellow|Red|Green
CCL2    FGTZ    6347    Receptor       Path4|Path5|Path2    Yellow|Pink|Blue
IL-1    SED     3552    Receptor       Path6|Path5|Path3    Purple|Pink|Red
PAI1    SWA     5054    Receptor       Path1                Green 
IL-12   SSS     3593    Receptor       Path1|Path2          Green|Blue 
IL-8    SDE     3576    Receptor       Path1|Path3|Path5    Green|Red|Pink
CTGF    SDFR    1490    Receptor       Path4|Path5|Path1    Yellow|Pink|Green
TGF     FDGT    7046    Receptor       Path5|Path3          Pink|Red
```

And I want to split the `cols` named `Paths` and `Colors`, and then count how many times each `Path#` appears on the column named `Paths`. So I can obtain a `df` like the one displayed below, where `Path1` appears 7 times and its corresponding color is `Green`. `Path5` appears 5 times, that is why is displayed in second place with its corresponding color (`pink`) and so on.

```
> df2
Paths Colors
Path1 Green
Path5 Pink
Path3 Red
Path2 Blue
Path4 Yellow
Path6 Purple
```

I tried with do to that with this code:

```
Paths <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$paths), '|', fixed = TRUE)))
df2 <- table(unlist(Paths))
df2 <- data.frame(sort(df2, decreasing = T))
```

But this is working just with one line and it is not spliting and separing the `Paths` and `Colors` cols together.

Any suggestions? Preferably using `base R`

Comment: Why does gene 3553 have only the first Path and Color, and 3569 has a color "Pink" which is not in its original data?

Comment: Because `cols` named `Paths` and `Colors` it is a summary about how many times `Paths` appear in `Path` column.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Gene 3569 has color "Pink" in your output data. Please explain where this comes from.

Comment: `Names`, `Symbol`, `GeneID` and `Description` remain the same. In `Path` and `Colors` I am counting the number of times `Path#` appears. For example, `Path1` appears 7 times in the whole column. That is why in the `df` I want to obtain, it appears first with his corresponding color. `Path5` appears 5 times, that is the reason why it appears as second with the corresponding color and so on.

Comment: So you want Path1 to be in the first row if it is the most common path, Path5 to be in the second row if it is the second most common path etc.?  And the same with colors? OK, why not edit your question to explain that. At the moment nobody is gonna have any idea what you want (and I just wasted 10 minutes answering the wrong question for you :-( )

Comment: I edited the question and yes, I want the most common paths appear first but without losing the name of its corresponding color. Aynway thank you for your suggestion and sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R` the answer is:

```
## This part of the script is to separate the Paths and Colors columns
Paths <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$Paths), '|', fixed = TRUE)))
Colors <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$Colors), '|', fixed = TRUE)))

## Here Paths and Colors are pasted together and separated by underscore
Pathways = data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(Paths), nrow = nrow(Colors)))

for (i in 1:ncol(Paths)){
  Pathways[,i] = paste(Paths[,i], Colors[,i], sep = " ")
}

## Then, the number of times that each Path appears is counted.
occurrences <- table(unlist(Pathways))
occurrences <- data.frame(sort(occurrences, decreasing = T))
occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question. First we need to reshape the data to a tidy format: one row per path with its corresponding colour.

```
df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(Paths, Colors, sep = "\\|") 

    Names Symbol GeneID Description Paths Colors
1   IL-1    CP1   3553    Receptor Path1  Green
2   IL-1    CP1   3553    Receptor Path2   Blue
3   IL-1    CP1   3553    Receptor Path5   Pink
...
```

Now we need to count the most popular paths:

```
counts <- df %>% count(Paths) %>% arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Paths     n
  <chr> <int>
1 Path1     7
2 Path5     6
3 Path3     5
4 Path2     4
5 Path4     3
6 Path6     1
```

Lastly we can join the corresponding colours and remove the `n` column. Here's one way.

```
counts %>% inner_join(df) %>% distinct(Paths, Colors)

Joining, by = "Paths"
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Paths Colors
  <chr> <chr> 
1 Path1 Green 
2 Path5 Pink  
3 Path3 Red   
4 Path2 Blue  
5 Path4 Yellow
6 Path6 Purple
```